# How do I merge the results of two Firestore Realtime listeners into one array of objects using React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to merge the data received from two real-time listeners into one `requests` array. The array contains objects as its elements. This is so I can pass one single `requests` prop and manipulate that in my Dashboard component.

In Firestore, my documents in my Requests collection contain `employeeUser` and `managerUser` as references to another Users collection which contains information about the user such as their username. So I am also trying to receive their username within my snapshot as well.

Here is an example of the fields in the document of the Requests collection:
[image: Example fields in a document of my Requests collection]

I am having issues merging the data from both listeners into one `requests` array using `useEffect` and `useState` hooks. Also, when I try to use the spread syntax to merge arrays it doesn't seem to actually have an effect on `setRequests`. When I use a callback `setRequests((prev) => [...prev, ...employeeRequests])` it doesn't seem to do anything either.

In a nutshell, with the current code I have below, I seem to be receiving the correct data in the console (only in managerRequests & employeeRequests arrays) but I cannot merge the two arrays together and it is not displaying properly after all renders have been completed.

I did also notice that while I am editing the code and make a change right after that involves requests, the hot reload re-renders the page once more and then everything displays correctly. Once I refresh the page, nothing displays again until I have another hot reload that affects `setRequests`. I am wondering if I have to trigger some more renders somehow to get all the updates in the useEffect dependency array.

Here is my code so far:

```
  const [requests, setRequests] = useState([]); // the array where I am trying to merge both managerRequests and employeeRequests into (cause its the only way I've been able to get it to kinda work)
  const [managerRequests, setManagerRequests] = useState([]);
  const [employeeRequests, setEmployeeRequests] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firebase) {
        
        //Set up first listener
      const unsubscribe = firebase.getManagerRequests({
        userUid: user.uid, onSnapshot: (snapshot) => {
          const managerRequests = [];
          snapshot.forEach(async doc => {

            const [managerPromise, employeePromise] = await Promise.all([doc.data().managerUser.get(), doc.data().employeeUser.get()]); // single get() queries to retrieve employee and manager usernames from referenced User collection
            var managerUsername = managerPromise.data().username;
            var employeeUsername = employeePromise.data().username;

            managerRequests.push({
              id: doc.id,
              managerUsername: managerUsername,
              employeeUsername: employeeUsername,
              ...doc.data()
            })

          })

          // console.log(managerRequests) -> managerRequests contains the correct set of data in an array of objects ex: [{id:1, ...}, {id:2, ...}]
          setManagerRequests(managerRequests);
          setLoadingElements((vals) => ({ ...vals, managerRequestsLoading: false })) // Currently not using these as barrier flags
        }
      })
      
      //Set up second listener
      const unsubscribetwo = firebase.getEmployeeRequests({
        userUid: user.uid, onSnapshot: (snapshot) => {
          const employeeRequests = [];
            snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
              const [managerPromise, employeePromise] = await Promise.all([doc.data().managerUser.get(), doc.data().employeeUser.get()]);
              var managerUsername = managerPromise.data().username;
              var employeeUsername = employeePromise.data().username;

              employeeRequests.push({
                id: doc.id,
                managerUsername: managerUsername,
                employeeUsername: employeeUsername,
                ...doc.data()
              })

            })    
          // console.log(employeeRequests) > employeeRequests contains the correct set of data in an array of objects ex: [{id:1, ...}, {id:2, ...}]
          setEmployeeRequests(employeeRequests);
          setLoadingElements((vals) => ({ ...vals, employeeRequestsLoading: false })) // Currently not using these as barrier flags
        }
      })

      setRequests([...managerRequests, ...employeeRequests]); // This does not seem to work. requests has nothing in it in the last render

      return () => {
        if (unsubscribe) {
          unsubscribe();
        }
        if (unsubscribetwo) {
          unsubscribetwo();
        }
      }

    }
  }, [firebase, user])
  
  
  console.log(requests) // contains nothing in requests
  
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Dashboard requests={requests} /> // This is where I want to pass an array of the merged employee and manager requests as a prop to my Dashboard component
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
```

**Edit: Here is how I fixed it with the help of the first answer:**

```
  const [requests, setRequests] = useState([]); 
  const [managerRequests, setManagerRequests] = useState([]);
  const [employeeRequests, setEmployeeRequests] = useState([]);
  const [managerUsername, setManagerUsername] = useState('');
  const [employeeUsername, setEmployeeUsername] = useState('');
  const [managerUsernameEmployeeSide, setManagerUsernameEmployeeSide] = useState('');
  const [employeeUsernameEmployeeSide, setEmployeeUsernameEmployeeSide] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firebase) {
        
        //Set up first listener
      const unsubscribe = firebase.getManagerRequests({
        userUid: user.uid, onSnapshot: (snapshot) => {
          const managerRequests = [];
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            // Had to remove await Promise.all(...) to get it to work
            
            doc.data().managerUser.get()
              .then(res => {
                setManagerUsername(res.data().username);
              })
              
             doc.data().employeeUser.get()
              .then(res => {
                setEmployeeUsername(res.data().username);
              })

            managerRequests.push({
              id: doc.id,
              managerUsername: managerUsername,
              employeeUsername: employeeUsername,
              ...doc.data()
            })

          })

          setManagerRequests(managerRequests);
        }
      })


      return () => {
        if (unsubscribe) {
          unsubscribe();
        }
      }

    }
  }, [firebase, user, managerUsername, employeeUsername])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firebase) {
        //Set up second listener
      const unsubscribetwo = firebase.getEmployeeRequests({
        userUid: user.uid, onSnapshot: (snapshot) => {
          const employeeRequests = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
              const [managerPromise, employeePromise] = await Promise.all([doc.data().managerUser.get(), doc.data().employeeUser.get()]);
              var managerUsername = managerPromise.data().username;
              var employeeUsername = employeePromise.data().username;
              
              doc.data().managerUser.get()
              .then(res => {
                setManagerUsernameEmployeeSide(res.data().username);
              })
              
             doc.data().employeeUser.get()
              .then(res => {
                setEmployeeUsernameEmployeeSide(res.data().username);
              })

              employeeRequests.push({
                id: doc.id,
                managerUsername: managerUsernameEmployeeSide,
                employeeUsername: employeeUsernameEmployeeSide,
                ...doc.data()
              })

            })    

          setEmployeeRequests(employeeRequests);

        }
      })
    }
    return () => {
        if (unsubscribetwo) {
          unsubscribetwo();
        }
    }
  }, [firebase, user, managerUsernameEmployeeSide, employeeUsernameEmployeeSide]
  
    useEffect(() => {
    if (managerRequests.length > 0 && employeeRequests.length > 0) {
      setTransactions([...managerRequests, ...employeeRequests]);
    }
  }, [managerRequests, employeeRequests])
  
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Dashboard requests={requests} /> // Requests finally receives one array with all values from managerRequests and employeeRequests combined
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subscribe to `firebase.getManagerRequests` and `firebase.getEmployeeRequests` with callbacks `(snapshot) => { // ... }`. Those callbacks will not be executed synchronously. They will be executed when  the responses of the requests come back. So there are no `managerRequests` and `employeeRequests` when your `setRequests([...managerRequests, ...employeeRequests])`.

Here is a simple example solution

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = React.useState([])
  const [state2, setState2] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Do the first subscribe
    // state1 will be updated in the subscription's callback
  }, [
    // Dependencies of this effect
  ])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Do the second subscribe
    // state2 will be updated in the subscription's callback
  }, [
    // Dependencies of this effect
  ])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Merge state1 and state2 here
  }, [
    state1, 
    state2
  ])
}
```

---- updated@20211203 ----

`setState` is asynchronous. You can checkout https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate for more information.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // for example
  console.log(state1) // [1, 2, 3]
  console.log(state2) // [7, 8, 9]

  setRequests([...state1, ...state2])
  console.log(requests) // this is not guaranteed to be [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
}. [state1, state2])
```

If you want to do something based on the merged requests in the same component. You can write another useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(requests) // [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
}, [requests])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I separated everything out into three useEffect functions and it looks like I am getting the same result. When I console log `requests` after the third useEffect, it is empty. When I modify the code again and hit save, the hot reload shows that `requests` has the correct data in the first few re-renders, then it is empty again once all the renders have finished. So the data is briefly there for a millisecond then it is empty again after a hot reload. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Hi @uponly. Are you `console.log(state1, state2)` inside the callback of `useEffect` or outside? It should work if you do it inside the callback of `useEffect`

Comment: Yes when I `console.log(state1, state2)` inside the third useEffect, the correct values are there for `state1` and `state2`. But right after the console.log, when I try to merge `state1` and `state2` into `requests` like so: `setRequests([...state1, ...state2])`, my `console.log(requests)` inside and outside the useEffect is empty. However, if I add this  `if (state1.length > 0 && state2.length > 0)` around `setRequests(...)`, the data finally appears on screen after the **second** re-render after making a change and saving my code (hot-reload). I feel like I am very close

Comment: I had updated the answer for you @uponly

Comment: Thank you @wtlin1228. I got it to work with your help, but I did not need the fourth useEffect. Instead, I removed the `await Promise.all(...)` and replaced it with a traditional callback and added username variables in the dependency array. I'll post my answer if you wanted to take a look